# Does Round(0.005) give a wrong result?

Tags: vba, excel, rounding

When I enter

```
Debug.Print(Round(0.005, 2))
 0
```

in the Immediate Window in VBA (Excel 2010) I get `0` as a result. I would have expected `0.01`.

I cannot imagine VBA calculating wrong so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's correct.  VBA uses [banker's rounding](http://wiki.c2.com/?BankersRounding).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a bankers rounding vs arithmetic rounding thing

```
  = Round(variable + 0.000001, 0)
```

Comment: as far as I know, it's not an error, it's the logic of Round:
it uses **round-to-even** logic

Comment: Thank you! I did a little research in the meantime - another solution is to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(0.005, 2)`

Comment: @tretom excuse my language more like its a thing of bankers rounding vs arithmetic rounding

Comment: @Doug Coats: exactly. nothing wrong with that what you've answered. I should have put the comment to the OP.